# Magento shipping charge based on specific zip code and weight range

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I need to calculate the shipping charge based on following to criteria.

- I have fixed specific pin codes available for shipment.
- The weight of the product.

Condition: If the weight of the product is within 500gms then free shipping otherwise on every 500gms additional price of Rs 50 will be added as shipping charge.

Kindly guide me as to how to achieve this in magento 1.9

Comment: you can use magento default table rate shipping , check this [link](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Ps4zWNXjM8qL8QfX9K6gCw&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+table+rate+shipping+based+on+weight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the Google drive link for the solution of this question and first disable all other shipping methods except this shipping then it will work properly.

Download the customised code according to the requirement.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RZxA4F3j3KWmo2WUFJWXE0ejQ/view

Comment: Lot of thanks for the help extended. But would like to have the shipment charges on total weight of the product in cart and not on each individual item in the cart. If the total weight of product in cart is greater than 500gms and less than 1kg then 50 rs should be charged. And on every additional 500gms the charge would be 50/-. Plus there is fixed delivery location according to zip codes. As i am a fresher, facing issue in fulfilling the requirement.

Comment: Replace  existing file from this uploaded file on below location
app\code\community\Inchoo\Shipping\Model
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RZxA4F3j3KSTBuNW1UOVlIM2c/view

Comment: Can i enable table rate shipping as well ? As i want to deliver the product only to specific pin codes.

Comment: Yes, you can enable.

Comment: I enabled but its taking it as two different shipping methods. I want in one only shipping method where it check for the pincode as well it display the shipping charge too on the checkout page.How is it possible ?